# Security filter chain does not permit requestsMatchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm building an eshop as an exercise and I want to permit all requests that does not require authorization, such as the list of products, the customer registration etc.

I managed to permit the login and the `GET` that returns a list of available products, but I can't make it work for the customer self registration.

I get error 403 because the token is not present (obviously).

This is my security filter chain:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/products/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/user/**").permitAll() //i think the problem is either here
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); 

    /*http.formLogin();  
    http.httpBasic();*/  

    return http.build();
}
```

I also tried to write that `requestMatchers` in this way:

```java
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/user/**")
```

or

```java
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/user/self-registration")
```

or

```java
.requestMatchers("/api/v1/user/self-registration")
```

but nothing changed.

I'm not even sure about one of the working ones, because if I got it right, this

```java
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET , "/api/v1/products/**").permitAll()
```

should permit all `GET` request of any endpoint that starts with `/api/v1/products`.
If this is the case, I can't add a request that only the admin can do.

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

- Java 17,
- Spring Boot 3.0,
- Spring Security  latest

**---- UPDATE ---**-

these are the security logs:

```
2023-04-21T16:42:12.328+02:00 DEBUG 13148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/v1/user/self-registration
2023-04-21T16:42:12.337+02:00 DEBUG 13148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-04-21T16:42:12.353+02:00 DEBUG 13148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [POST /api/v1/user/self-registration] with attributes [permitAll]
2023-04-21T16:42:12.353+02:00 DEBUG 13148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /api/v1/user/self-registration
2023-04-21T16:42:12.373+02:00 DEBUG 13148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-04-21T16:42:12.376+02:00 DEBUG 13148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-04-21T16:42:12.376+02:00 DEBUG 13148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [authenticated]
2023-04-21T16:42:12.376+02:00 DEBUG 13148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

These are the request headers.
I also tried to add the "Authorization" header empty and with the "Bearer " but without any token after that. It wasn't the problem

[image: Request headers]

**----- SOLVED -----**

I finally soved it

First of all I learned that i can add multiple strings to the same `.requestMatchers()` method

so for the moment the filter chan has this request matchers

```
.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**","/api/v1/user/selfregistration")   
            .permitAll()
```

Then I got `error 404 not found`, i had to change my controller and now it's working fine

ty

Comment: the problem seems with your "registration process" (auth provider, jwtFilter, ...), since up till `POST /api/v1/user/self-registration` security logging looks "normal", but then (suddenly) tries/fails to "authorize `/error`" endpoint ... (with `.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()` you could little proceed with/get info from that)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are building a service that exposes REST API, below configuration is working fine for me

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/products/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").permitAll()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return new NimbusJwtDecoder(jwtProcessor());
    }

    private JWTProcessor<SecurityContext> jwtProcessor() {
        return new DefaultJWTProcessor<>();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/auth/{id}")
    public String auth(@PathVariable String id) {
        return id;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/products/{id}")
    public String getProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
        return id;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/users/{id}")
    public String getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        return id;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/secured/{id}")
    public String getSecuredResource(@PathVariable String id) {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Curl requests:

```
curl localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/username                                                                                                                                                                               
username                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

curl localhost:8080/api/v1/products/product1                                                                                                                                                                           
product1
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
curl localhost:8080/api/v1/users/user1                                                                                                                                                                                 
user1
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
curl localhost:8080/api/v1/secured/id
```

I don't have your complete security configuration class to see if there is an issue with your configuration. Hope this helps.